# Count mixture of cells and merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

i have a problem with counting Merge cells as the code i've used counts every cell including those that are merged together. Right now i have the formula to count all the cells inclusive of the cells that are merged together for example if i merge 6 cells together, i would want it to be counted as 1 but it counts as 6. Is there a way to count a mixture of both single cells and merged cells? Thank you for the help (:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each rCell In rRange
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
vResult = 1 + vResult
End If
Next rCell
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

You could consider using a dictionary to keep track of the address of any merged area that you have counted already. That would mean that merged areas could cover multiple rows and would still only be counted once. [This](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) is a good website that describes the use of a dictionary object. You would have to add 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' as reference.

Try something like this:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim mergedAreaAddressBook As New Scripting.Dictionary

i = 0

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = wks.Range("A1:H6")

'For each cell in the range
For Each c In rng

  'If the adress of the merged area is not on your dictionary
  If Not mergedAreaAddressBook.Exists(c.MergeArea.Address) Then

      'Increment the counter
      i = i + 1

      'Add the cell address to your address book
      mergedAreaAddressBook.Add c.MergeArea.Address, c.MergeArea.Address

  End If

Next c
```

For a range that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcG4t.jpg), the value of i will be 34 when the sub ends.

There is probably an easier way to do it but that's all I can think of right now!

Good luck with your solution, I hope this helps a little.